# Sleep mode no longer works after the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, sleep, acpi, windows-10-v1709

Last week I've updated my PC with the latest Windows 10 Fall Creators Update. Since then, I cannot longer use a sleep mode on the PC - when I try to put the PC to sleep, it doesn't go to sleep but to a some "special state":

- the power LED is turned off (instead of blinking)
- after the first pressing of the power button, nothing happens
- after the second pressing of the power button PC boots normally (as if it was turned off, not sleeping)

I checked the Event Viewer System Log and it shows this error (after every start form this "special mode"):

> Event 41, Kernel-Power, The system has rebooted without cleanly
>   shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped
>   responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

Of course, I've updated BIOS and all my drivers to the latest version, but it didn't help.

My configuration:

- MB: Asus P6X58D-E
- RAM: 6x Corsair XMS3 CM3X2G1600C9 2 GB (12 GB)
- CPU: Intel Core i7-930
- GPU: Gigabyte GeForce GTX 750 Ti

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with a similar issue since a few weeks now. My computer did not enter sleep mode at all, but instead went to the lock screen. Here is what solved the issue for me:
Control Panel >> Power Options >> Edit Plan Settings (your active plan) >> Change advanced power settings >> Sleep >>

- Allow hybrid sleep: SET TO OFF
- Allow wake timers: SET TO DISABLE

About "Allow hybrid sleep":
I have a Samsung 950 PRO 512 and 64GB of memory with a 40 GB RamDrive. I do NOT want windows to write all this stuff on my drive every time i enter sleep mode!

About "Allow wake timers":
When I put my computer to sleep, I want it to sleep! No software, driver, what-so-ever should interfere with my decision.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I went through the advanced power options and fixed for maximum economy, then i ran:
powercfg -requests
result:
SYSTEM:
[DRIVER] Realtek High Definition Audio (HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0282&SUBSYS_1043119D&REV_1000\4&6824705&0&0001)
Аудиопоток уже используется.
it turns out skype was using the audio driver!